# Low precision after smote

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, scikit-learn, unbalanced-classes

I am working on a classification problem with class imbalance. I implemented every kind of balance technique and I always get high accuracy, recall and roc (0.85) and low precision( around 0.50). Also I've done params  tuning but I always end up dropping the recall when I maximize precision due to their trade off. Do you have any suggestions on how to increase the precision without dropping recall very much?

Comment: What metric are you optimizing in your hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: Weighted Fscore with a slight bias towards recall

Comment: Ok good. What are the validation scores with and without SMOTE applied? How was it set up in that case.